# Returning a JavaScript function called from JavaScript function error

Tags: javascript

I have no idea how to explain this, I'll just show you want I am trying to do

I have a JavaScript function that adds new content to a div

```
function stopUpload(success) {
  document.getElementById("load-content").innerHTML = success + document.getElementById("load-content").innerHTML;
}
```

however, success has a JavaScript function inside it:

```
success = '
        //more html
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">                   
            $(\"body\").share({
                onClickId: \"share-default-29\",
                owner: \"brfieger\",
                description: \"asdasdasdasd\",
                image: \"\",
                pid: \"29\",
                type: \"status\"
            });                     
        </script>   
        //more html
    ';
```

I am getting an error because it is recognizing

```
</script>
```

and is terminating the script

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

If it matters, I am calling stopUpload like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.top.window.stopUpload('//success content above');
</script>
```

I have no idea how to fix this, I would assume the script is encapsulated inside a string and wouldn't be recognized until being evaluated, but it is

Also, for readability I made new lines. In the code all new lines are converted to \n

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the JS from the example, anyway, try executing what is between the script tags, literally as it is. Most likely the error is escaping the strings, inside the html when you shouldn't. ie: `$(\"body\")`

Comment: I removed just </script> and everything worked as expected, it isn't a problem with escaping the html outisde the script or js inside the script

Comment: :l the stackoverflow highlighting tricked me!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `'</script>'` your script will terminate. Then, you can use `'</scr'+'ipt>'`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEh2x/)

---

Note: the code above avoids errors, but doesn't execute the script.

If you want to execute it, you should use DOM methods:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = "alert('a')";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEh2x/1/)

Comment: This however doesn't evaluate what is inside the script